# Seeking school quality data?

Tags: usa

I need to create a map that shows school quality in Atlanta. I'm having a really hard time finding either test score data or school proficiency data.

Where or how can I search for this?

Comment: also specify what kind of file/format you would want your data in. shapefile, csv,geojson...

Comment: And what school types...

Comment: Wow...I guess I am more lost on this school project than I realized. I guess I would want a shape file but I did some googling and I think I can create a shapefile from a csv. Is that right? As for school types, I think high school but I'll take anything I can find at this point.

Answer (score 2):

The "2018 CCRPI Data Report" [PDF](https://www.atlantapublicschools.us/cms/lib/GA01000924/Centricity/Domain/10223/2018%20APS%20CCRPI%20Data%20Report.pdf) report from https://www.atlantapublicschools.us has tabular data quantifying schools. You can easily copy/paste to Excel or similar tool.

[image]

You'd need still to map these schools, but since there are not thousands, you could do so manually, or with a [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) API.

---

You can also consider filing a FOIA request to https://www.atlantapublicschools.us for the data, but then you'd have to very specifically define what you need.